# Discord bot using javascript .sendMessage is not a function

Tags: javascript, npm, bots, npm-install, discord

I am working on a bot and I am trying to get it to send a message using .sendMessage

(I do not want it to message when I type something, so I dont want to use

```
bot.on("message", function(message) {});
```

However I am getting .sendMessage is not a function

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const getJSON = require('get-json');
const BotToken = "token";
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.login(BotToken); 

bot.sendMessage('serverid', 'test');
```

I have done npm install discord.js as I thought it was part of the discord.js package.

.setStreaming gives the same error too. Most if not all of the functions from here give the error http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html their tutorial says to use npm install --save --msvs_version=2015 discord.js which I have done.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please provide the code so that other users can see **why** `.sendMessage is not a function`

Comment: edited my original post with it

Comment: [`bot.loginWithToken(BotToken, successCallback)`](http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#logging-in-with-a-token). You're not waiting for a response and you're passing a token to the wrong login function

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to send a message to the server itself, but you can only send to channels. Also, sendMessage is deprecated and you should use send instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out how to do this. I'll include a clip of my code here. I'm going to use my code to send messages at timed intervals, so my clip will include some other stuff that's not specifically what you're asking, but hopefully you can use my code to get a good understanding of what you need in your code. The part that makes this work the way you're is the first chunk.

```
var NotifyChannel;
bot.on('ready', () => {
  NotifyChannel = bot.channels.find("id", "347400244461568011");
});

var sched = later.parse.text('every 2 mins on the 30th sec');

function logTest() {
  NotifyChannel.send("This is a two minute test.");
  console.log(`Please only do this once, please. ${retrieveDate()}` + 
  `${retrieveTimestamp()}`);
  return;
}

var timer = later.setInterval(function(){ logTest(); }, sched)
```

Edit: formatting

Answer (score 0):

To use `.setPresence` and a streaming url, it must be added to the ready function.

I'll include very simple code you can copy and paste, if that will help you understand the functions in your question:

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', message => {
    var prefix = '!';
    if (msg === prefix + 'ping') {
      message.channel.send('pong!')
    }
});

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Connecting...');
    bot.user.setStatus('available') // Can be 'available', 'idle', 'dnd', or 'invisible'
    bot.user.setPresence({
        game: {
            name: 'MESSAGE', // What 'Now Playing:' reads
            type: 0,
            url: 'URL' // Replace with twitch.tv/channel url
        }
    });
});

bot.login('TOKEN');
```